# Insert columns into rows for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

table 1:

```
    ID       name 
---------  -----------
    1         john
    2         salma
    3         tony
```

table2:

```
    ID         Tasks      amount
---------  -----------  ----------
    1         write         2
    1         memorize      3
    1         read          6
    1         sing         NULL
    2         write         1
    2         memorize     NULL
    2         read          5
    2         sing         NULL
    3         write        NULL
    3         memorize      8
    3         read          2
    3         sing         NULL
```

I want to insert new columns in table1 for each task mentioned in table2.

Table1:

```
    ID        name       write    memorize    read    sing
---------  ----------- --------  ---------  ------- --------
    1         john        2          3         6      NULL
    2         salma       1         NULL       5      NULL
    3         tony       NULL        8         2      NULL
```

I can do the insert in Table1 for one `ID` at a time, but not for all of them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there's a finite and known number of possible values corresponding to the columns being added, what's stopping you from adding them explicitly as a one-time operation?  If there *isn't*, then I *highly* recommend *not* doing this.  Dynamic schemas is relational databases are a famously bad idea.

Comment: @David this is just an example of a much larger table, so doing it explicitly is not an option. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Why not?  How many columns are we talking about here?  If there are *hundreds* of columns then this might not be the best approach in the first place.  Even still, explicitly defining them doesn't necessarily mean typing them all in by hand.  You can `SELECT DISTINCT` on the data to get the column names and take that list into any text editor to quickly wrap the column names in pre-defined `ALTER TABLE` snippets to add the columns.

Comment: Which database and version?

Comment: @David There is 17 column to insert, but the number of rows is not finite. It's a query table that may have hundreds of rows at some point. it depends on how many entries there is by the user. I am not sure how to turn the rows to columns for each ID there is. I was able to do it for one `ID` at a time, but not for all the `ID`s.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Microsoft SQL 2008

Comment: Since the data is already in the db in its current format, it makes sense that something needs it to be formatted the way that it is.  Creating a new table with the same data with a different format means the data will be stored in duplicate and will have to be maintained as the source data changes.  It seems (since you know the 17 values the need to become columns) that you could create a view with a PIVOT query to reformat the data, which means the data will only be stored once, and you won't need to keep the duplicate data synchronized with its source.

Comment: @JamesL. `Pivot` worked great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I inserted the row values in a temporary table as columns using `pivot`:

```
 select * into #Results 
        from
        (
          select ID,Tasks,amount
          from #Table2

        ) tb2
    pivot
    (
      max(amount)
      for ID in ([1], [2], [3])
    ) as piv
```

Then, I did an `inner join` with Table1:

```
select * from Table1 tb1 inner join #Results r on r.ID =tb1.ID
```

Thanks @JamesL for the seggustion to use `pivot`!